# undefined reference to `dlopen' despite CMAKE_DL_LIBS

Tags: 13.10, c++, cmake

I'm trying to install the tools for gameplay3d. After following the [cmake installation instructions](https://github.com/blackberry/GamePlay/wiki/Building-gameplay-encoder), I get this error:

```
Linking CXX executable gameplay-encoder
/usr/lib/gcc4/x64/release/libfbxsdk.so: undefined reference to `dlopen'
/usr/lib/gcc4/x64/release/libfbxsdk.so: undefined reference to `dlclose'
/usr/lib/gcc4/x64/release/libfbxsdk.so: undefined reference to `dlsym'
```

The CMakeLists.txt file comes with these definitions (notice `-ldl` and `${CMAKE_DL_LIBS}`, which seemed to solve the problem for others in related threads):

```
add_definitions(-lstdc++ -ldl -lfbxsdk -lpng -lz -lfreetype -lpthread)
...
target_link_libraries(
    ${APP_NAME}
    ${APP_LIBRARIES}
    ${CMAKE_DL_LIBS}
)
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Problem "solved" by using the binary that is distributed with the library.
Still a very strange error, though.

Comment: Got the same problem here... 64bit Ubuntu 13.10 and I built the library which misses `dlopen` myself. Unfortunately there is nothing distributed that I can use here :/
I'm trying to build Pluma for a custom thirdparty set of CxxProf.
It works without problems on a 32bit Debian...

Answer (score 1):

As I wrote in a comment:
I just had the same problem on a Ubuntu 13.10 64bit. I'm not sure if the cause of our issue is the same Ubuntu version, as I solved it as follows:

I used a self-compiled version of the [Pluma library](http://pluma-framework.sourceforge.net/). Whenever I tried to compile my [own project](https://github.com/monsdar/CxxProf) which used that Pluma lib, I got the error you mentioned above. I tried to add `${CMAKE_DL_LIBS}` like you, but had no success.

The reason was, that I had to manually link Pluma with `libdl` at first (add `-ldl`). After that I could use `libPluma.so` without problems. I'm not sure, why Pluma compiled without `-ldl`, but I can only guess that it's something with the linker not working properly.

So to make it short (and answer your actual question):
You need to link `libfbxsdk.so` with `-ldl`, it does not help to just link `gameplay-encoder` with it.

Comment: Sadly this doesn't work for me, when building sqlite with CMake 3.1